# Render cutting out under Picture Box

Tags: c#, forms

I'm building a game by drawing to a form, but When ever said form goes off screen or a picture box covers part of the form, the image cuts off.

Why does this happen, and how can I stop it without constantly redrawing the screen?

Edit: I'm in an online class, so I can't read api
Edit2: I'm off by 3, so I should start reading by then

Edit3: Here's Some Of My Code That Fires Each Frame (Time.time is the time in seconds, and CloneInBoxAllSprites Renders all sprites as picture boxes, Backroundrender.output is the background)

```cs
        //Rerender Player
        CloneInBoxAllSprites(Player);

        //Make Sure Script Rendered Background
        if (Time.time < 1)
        {
            //Rerender Background
            RerenderBackGround(0, 15);

            //Draw Render To Controll
            graphics.DrawImage(BackGroundRender.output, 0, 0);
        }
```

Edit4: clarity

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: For example, draw a square to the from and move the partially off the screen, so that you can't see the square. Then move it back, and the square will be gone.

Comment: Us writing the code you describe in no way would identify the specific issues you are encountering. You need to provide the code that you have tried, not describe generic issues.

Comment: Alright, Online class has ended early, so I'll do that now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for being vague, but I figured out the issue. The `Graphics.DrawImage()` method can't draw large pictures fast, and as the background was rendered as a large bitmap so drawing it was slow.

But, by declaring a picture box ans setting it's image to the background render, I was able to skip using the `Graphics.DrawImage()` method, and saving time and resources while allowing me to redraw it each frame.

Thanks for all the help!